# Number of Http Request differences between Remoting and Wcf

Tags: wcf, http

I currently have an application which is using remoting and I wanted to test converting it to use Wcf. I was able to convert the application without any issues but I found something interesting in Fiddler and I wanted to see if this was "normal".

When I make 1 remoting call, I get 1 Http request in Fiddler. When I make 1 using Wcf, I get 4 Http request.

Is there something that I am missing or not understanding?

I'm using .Net 3.5 SP 1 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using wshttp binding whihc involves a secure conversation establishment. Try using basic http binding without security.